# Ember extended and attributes

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Hi i have this code and the problem is that defaultFilter doesnt change when i walk to the Recent route, the line

> this.controllerFor('images').set('selectedFilter', this.get('defaultFilter'));

gets interpreted as defaultFilter is always 'Popular' even when i go to other routes (like Recent route)

```
App.ImagesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    defaultFilter: 'Popular'
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('images', {
            controller: 'images'
        });
    },
    setupController: function (_, model) {
        this.controllerFor('images').set('content', model);
        this.controllerFor('images').set('selectedFilter', this.get('defaultFilter'));
    }
});

App.ImagesRecentRoute = App.ImagesRoute.extend({
    defaultFilter: 'Recent'
});
```

Any ideas what I've done wrong? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Looks fine, it should work](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/meyivemu/1/edit).

The only thing I notice is that you are missing comma (,) after `defaultFilter`. Not sure if that's copy-paste error or you forgot to check your console.

Comment: Even in your example i dont see the Filter: thing and yea it was a copy paste typo

Comment: You're supposed to see `Filter: Recent`, which has overridden `defaultFilter: "Popular"` from `App.ImagesRoute`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I think something in my controller broke my code by observing the selectedFilter and messing with it, Ill go deeper into my code probably problem from my side. Does going to images.recent runs both the setupController of images and of imagesRecent?

Comment: It will pass through `images` on its way to `images.recent`, so it will run it there once. If going directly to `images.recent`, it will run the most shallow version of method it can find. In this case, it is `ImagesRoute.setupController`. If you add `setupController` to `images.recent`, it will run that one. If you want the overriden method executed as well, call `this._super()`;

Comment: Oh i see when my page url is 127.0.0.0.1/#/images/recent and i press enter(on the url bar) it calls to ImagesRoute and then to ImagesRecentRoute.  
When i click inside my app on a link to images.recent and goes directly to ImagesRecentRoute without touching the ImagesRoute